# Casting from Decimal to Float

Tags: c#, asp.net, casting, floating-point, decimal

I am doing a little bit of mathematical calculations. Here is my code:

```
   decimal FirstYr = decimal.Round((first / second), 5);
```

If I am passing `first = 20` and `second = 34`, I am getting the value of **0.58824** in **FirstYr**. Which is fine. Now I am doing this calculation here in my **LINQ**:

```
   ev.HiComm = (float)(FirstYr * 100);
```

**HiComm** is float in the **DB** and this above calculation is passing value: **58.824001312255859**

Which I dont want it. I want in my `ev.HiComm = 58.824`

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: This may interest you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122523/why-is-a-sql-float-different-from-a-c-float

Comment: Any reason you don't just multiple first line of code by 100

Comment: I can do that, but either way I need to convert it to float!

Comment: @Luke: I tried your approach and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: I created a unit test for the code you have above, and it works for me. Hopefully someone will give a real answer, I don't see why moving the * 100 should make it work :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked like this in the code behind:

```
 decimal FirstYr = decimal.Round((first / second), 5)*100;
 ev.HiComm = (double)FirstYr ;
```

Thanks for all your suggestions!

Comment: All you did was cast a decimal to a double which begs the question the reason you are using a float ( decmial ) value in the database to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

if you want exactly 3 places after the point, you'll have to change your sql field to be `decimal(x,3)` where x is 3 plus the maximum places you'll need before the decimal. `float` is incapable of storing the exact value you want.

Comment: process the value read from the db back into your desired format? if your value needs to be that precise, `float` is going to be insufficient.

Comment: @Mayank Raj: The only thing you can do is round the value back to 3 decimals whenever you fetch it from the DB.

Comment: @lincolnk: Lack of precision is not the problem. The problem is wanting to store decimal fractions in a binary format.

Comment: @Michael: It actually is for creating reports/jobs in MSSQL 2008. I cannot do that. The only option I have is to either change the datatype in DB or change something in my code behind...

Comment: @Mayank Raj: then change the DB datatype - that's the actually correct solution.