# Casting float to decimal loses precision in C#

Tags: c#, .net, casting, floating-point, decimal

In C# 4.0, the following cast behaves very unexpectedly:

```
(decimal)1056964.63f
1056965
```

Casting to double works just fine:

```
(double)1056964.63f
1056964.625

(decimal)(double)1056964.63f
1056964.625
```

Is this by design?

Comment: Also, it may be worth noting a SQL Server float is not the same as a .NET float.  They are not the same.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122523/why-is-a-sql-float-different-from-a-c-sharp-float

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is with your initial value - `float` is only accurate to 7 significant decimal digits anyway:

```
float f = 1056964.63f;
Console.WriteLine(f); // Prints 1056965
```

So really the *second* example is the unexpected one in some ways.

Now the *exact* value in `f` is 1056965.625, but that's the value given for all values from about 1056964.563 to 1056964.687 - so even the ".6" part isn't always correct. That's why the docs for `System.Single` state:

> By default, a Single value contains only 7 decimal digits of precision, although a maximum of 9 digits is maintained internally.

The extra information is still preserved when you convert to `double`, because that's can preserve it without "interpreting" it at all - where converting it to a decimal form (either to print or for the `decimal` type) goes through code which knows it can't "trust" those last two digits.

Comment: Not true. In this case float can actually hold value `1056964.63`, it's the formatting that rounds it to 1056965. Quote from COMNumber::FormatSingle in SSCLI: "In order to give numbers that are both friendly to display and round-trippable, we parse the number using 7 digits and then determine if it round trips to the same value.  If it does, we convert that NUMBER to a string, otherwise we reparse using 9 digits and display that."

Comment: @MagnatLU: It can't actually hold xxx.63. It can hold xxx.625 - but that value is also the closest value to xxx.68, so it's not really *accurate* even to the ".6" part. Read my edited answer and see whether you agree with that more.

Comment: I think .NET's `float` is exact implementation of IEEE-754 in which floating point number has exact value determined by it's exponent and fraction and the exact value is used for every calculation (`float` operations are JITted to coprocessor instructions). It's only the conversion to `string` or `COMNumber` when CLI uses custom approach and drops last *signignificant and precise* digits.

Comment: @MagnatLU: Yes - see my final paragraph. It's when the bits need to be *interpreted* as being significant, and that includes a conversion to `decimal`.

Comment: Okay. From the strict floating point rules you can trust those digits, but implementation chooses not to during certain operations. It makes sense for non-sci calculations. I guess your answer is more precise than mine anyway.

Answer (score -1):

It is by design. Float can hold your number [*edit*]quite accurate[*/edit*], but for conversion purposes to it rounds it up to nearest integer, because there are only few representable float values between your number and integer (1056964.75 and 1056964.88). See COMNumber::FormatSingle and COMDecimal::InitSingle from SSCLI.

Comment: No, it can't precisely hold the value - otherwise the conversion to `double` would print out 1056964.63 rather than 1056964.625.

Comment: You are right. But my point is that the Yurik's results were due to non-IEEE handling during conversion, not due to actual precision loss in representation.