# how to convert datatable into float

Tags: c#, datatable

i am filling datatable from db.below code

```
SUM(CONVERT(float, REPLACE(Quantity, CHAR(0), ''))) as Quantity,
```

from datatable now i need to convert into float so i tried below code

```
float s1 = 0;
foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
{
   s1 = _dr.Field<float>("Quantity");
}
```

but its showing error

```
Specified cast is not valid.
```

where i made error.

Comment: The error should specifically indicate what the *actual* type of the object is.  What is it?

Comment: Which version of .NET are you using? @Servy: older versions didn't indicate the actual type.

Comment: Use `double`
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122523/why-is-a-sql-float-different-from-a-c-sharp-float

Comment: error cleared by using double thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do this:

```
s1 = Convert.ToDouble( _dr["Quantity"]);
```

or

```
s1 = (float) _dr["Quantity"];
```

Comment: @T McKeown , @Happy ,  it there Convert.ToFloat() method in lib..?

Comment: actually...  float.Parse(stringVal) or Convert.ToDouble() is what should be used.

Answer (score 0):

Below code worked for me :
float.Parse(_dr["Quantity"].ToString());

Answer (score -3):

you are doing down casting in wrong manner, 
you have need to correct you statement as

```
float s1 = 0;
foreach (DataRow _dr in obj_dt.Rows)
{
 s1 = Convert.ToSingle(_dr["Quantity"]);
}
```

done

Comment: You shouldn't convert a numeric value to a string, just to parse it again as a numeric value, just to unbox it.