# why is this specified cast not valid??

Tags: c#, sql, floating-point, sqldatareader

[image]

i use the following code to map data from sql reader to C# Objects. the Power is of data type float in both code and sql database .. y is the cast error message occuring?

```
private Entity.PanelDetail MapDataReader(SqlDataReader dataReader)
    {
        Entity.PanelDetail panelDetail = new Entity.PanelDetail();
        panelDetail.IdPanelDetail = DataReaderExtensions.GetStringOrNull(dataReader, "idPanelDetail");
        panelDetail.IdDeviceDetail = DataReaderExtensions.GetStringOrNull(dataReader, "idDeviceDetail");
        panelDetail.Power = DataReaderExtensions.GetFloatOrNull(dataReader, "Power");
        panelDetail.Current = DataReaderExtensions.GetFloatOrNull(dataReader, "Current");
        panelDetail.Length = DataReaderExtensions.GetFloatOrNull(dataReader, "Length");
        panelDetail.Width = DataReaderExtensions.GetFloatOrNull(dataReader, "Width");
        panelDetail.CreatedBy = DataReaderExtensions.GetStringOrNull(dataReader, "CreatedBy");
        panelDetail.CreationDate = DataReaderExtensions.GetDateTimeOrNull(dataReader, "CreationDate");
        panelDetail.ModifiedBy = DataReaderExtensions.GetStringOrNull(dataReader, "ModifiedBy");
        panelDetail.ModifiedDate = DataReaderExtensions.GetDateTimeOrNull(dataReader, "ModifiedDate");
        panelDetail.IsActive = DataReaderExtensions.GetBoolOrNull(dataReader, "IsActive");
        panelDetail.IsDeleted = DataReaderExtensions.GetBoolOrNull(dataReader, "IsDeleted");

        return panelDetail;
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is a SQL float different from a C# float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122523/why-is-a-sql-float-different-from-a-c-sharp-float)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

My guess that the value is being returned as a boxed `double` instead of `float`. Try to use

```
 (float) dataReader.GetDouble(fieldOrdinal);
```

See [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx)

Comment: that means i will also have to change all attributes to double in my codE?

Comment: so if i change all attributes to double and am using GetDoubleOrNull then i dun have to use type cast: (float)dataReader.GetDouble(fieldOrdinal) ryt?

Comment: i just tried .. now its giving the following error:
 An exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: check your fieldOrdinal.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46987/discussion-between-sameer-and-sana-91)

Comment: Sameer, thanks a lot for the guidance... the problem got solved :)

Answer (score 6):

I would make a good bet that the data type being return is actually a (boxed) double.

***Update:*** Actually I just found that an SQL float maps to a .NET double on MSDN (so yes this is your problem): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx

Try this as a test:

`(float)dataReader.GetDouble(fieldOrdinal);`

Comment: @Sana.91 Yes, I would recommend that.

Comment: then should i use get float or null, or Get double or null method? because data type in my database are floats

Comment: @Sana.91 Use GetDouble or null. It's a float in the database when when it reaches .NET it's a double. You can see for yourself in the link I posted how it maps.

Comment: so if i change all attributes to double and am using GetDoubleOrNull then i dun have to use type cast: (float)dataReader.GetDouble(fieldOrdinal)

ryt?

Comment: @Sana.91 No then just stick with double. No need for float.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that SQL Float is double in .net. You can see the complete mapping [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx). Therefore, as others have suggested you need to read double and then try to cast it to float.

```
(float)dataReader.GetDouble("Power");
```