# Error when trying to load data from SQL datatable into DataView

Tags: sql, ml.net

I have created a SQL table with below code:

```
CREATE TABLE AAPL_1day
(
    [INDEX] INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    [DateTime] SMALLDATETIME NOT NULL,
    [MonthNr] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    [DayNr] FLOAT NOT NULL,
    [roc_1] FLOAT,
    [roc_2] FLOAT,
    [hypo_upordown7days] FLOAT
);
```

First rows in the table looks like this:
[image]

The problem I have now is to load this table into the variable "data" below.

I use `var preview = data.Preview();` to be able to see if there is any data loaded into "data". However `var preview` is null.

I get the error below when running the code:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

All columns in databaseName: AAPL have the datatype FLOAT. In the class "AAPLData" I have assigned "float" to all columns.

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I connect to the database and table successfully with the connection string and table name.

Even if I try to only retrieve one column, for example the below,
I still get the same error:

```
[LoadColumn(2)] public float MonthNr;
```

Code:

```
void loadInData()
{
    // Set up MLContext
    var mlContext = new MLContext();

    // Define database connection parameters
    string databaseName = "AAPL";
    string connectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=" + databaseName + ";Trusted_Connection=True;";
    var tableName = "AAPL_1day";

    var loader = mlContext.Data.CreateDatabaseLoader<AAPLData>();
    var source = new DatabaseSource(SqlClientFactory.Instance, connectionString, $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}");
    var data = loader.Load(source);
    var preview = data.Preview(); //System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'

    string dummy_breakpoint = ""; //Break point here
}

public class AAPLData
{
    [LoadColumn(2)] public float MonthNr;
    [LoadColumn(3)] public float DayNr;
    [LoadColumn(4)] public float roc_1;
    [LoadColumn(5)] public float roc_2;
    [LoadColumn(6), ColumnName("Label")] public float hypo_upordown7days;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the following SO answer, a SQL `float` is actually a `double`, so the data type coming back is a `double` and you'd need to convert it to a `float`.

[Why is a SQL float different from a C# float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122523/why-is-a-sql-float-different-from-a-c-sharp-float)

Comment: That is amazing. I just couldn't understand what was the problem. It is the first time I use ML.net and the SQL. I found a link on your link for equivalents for different datatypes between SQL and C# which is a great help in this. Thanks alot for your help!

Comment: No problem! I'm really glad it helped! :)